# starting apache2 in a single process mode

Tags: linux, apache2

I am trying to start apache2 package of the following version installed to ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) system.

```
pkg -l |grep apache2
ii  apache2                                               2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  apache2-bin                                           2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server (binary files and modules)
ii  apache2-data                                          2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5                                    all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)
```

By issuing the following command.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apache2 -X
```

But, I encountered the following error.

```
[Thu Oct 08 14:39:35.673168 2015] [core:warn] [pid 13875] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Thu Oct 08 14:39:35.673281 2015] [core:warn] [pid 13875] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Thu Oct 08 14:39:35.673289 2015] [core:warn] [pid 13875] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Thu Oct 08 14:39:35.673305 2015] [core:warn] [pid 13875] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Oct 08 14:39:35.676133 2015] [core:warn] [pid 13875:tid 140047429457792] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Oct 08 14:39:35.676463 2015] [core:warn] [pid 13875:tid 140047429457792] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Oct 08 14:39:35.676533 2015] [core:warn] [pid 13875:tid 140047429457792] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00543: apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve the issue?
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is unable to access `envvars` file  . Try to start it by using `apache2ctl`. Path is `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl`.